# Mat-table scroll only on body

Tags: css, angular, mat-table

I want to use CSS to scroll only the mat-table body. I can see the scroll but the table Thead becomes a mess.
The scroll is there but the disposition is not right

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QszI5.png)
this is the code i used for the tbody. when i remove the display block its gets back to normal but without scroll bar.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
tbody {
        border-spacing: 0;
        height:78vh;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 85vh;
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;

    }
```